# Access 2016 report header VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I am about to ask is, I hope simple knowledge question.

The command 'CreateReport' in MS Access VBA creates a blank report draft. However, there are only page header and page footer. What I would like to achive is to create blank report draft which includes also report header and report footer.
I could add them manualy after I create normal report draft, but then this is not what I want.

Is there any way to do it ?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Sub TestReportCreate()

    Dim rpt As Access.Report

    Set rpt = Application.CreateReport
    ' report is created minimized
    DoCmd.Restore
    ' toggle Header/Footer ON
    Application.RunCommand acCmdReportHdrFtr

    ' Do something with the header
    rpt.Section(acHeader).BackColor = RGB(255, 192, 192)

End Sub
```

but using the `ReportTemplate` parameter may be easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It always good to know more !! 

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way out. What I did is I have created blank report with manualy added report header and footer, and used as a draft.